# Cannot connect to docker image with localhost port mapping

Tags: python, docker, data-science

I am trying to build a reusable docker image for NLP data projects.  I have built a Dockerfile in the following way:

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHON_PACKAGES="\
    numpy \
    matplotlib \
    scipy \
    scikit-learn \
    pandas \
    nltk \
    wordcloud \
    spacy \ 
" 

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install jupyter

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--allow-root"]
```

Note that the docker image composes correctly with all of my dependencies in the requirements file.  However, when I attempt to connect on the local host, my attempt is rejected.  I ran the container using the following:

```
docker run -dp 9999:9999 tdnlptools
```

I validated that the container is running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
c26b647a1403   tdnlptools   "jupyter notebook --…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:9999->9999/tcp   modest_mcnulty
```

Yet, when I attempt to use the following connection, it won't work:

```
https://localhost:9999/
```

The error is:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Any idea why my connection is being refused?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Jupyter notebook listens on port 8888 by default.
2. Jupyter notebook binds to `localhost` by default, so it cannot be accessed from outside of the container.

You first need to arrange for Jupyter notebook to find to "all addresses" by adding the `--ip` command line option in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--allow-root", "--ip", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Now if you start a container like this:

```
docker run -dp 8888:8888 tdnlptools
```

You can connect to http://localhost:8888.

The output of `jupyter-notebook --help` documents a variety of other options that may be of interest.

Comment: thank you!  This worked!  I had to disable password access into the jupyter environment so I modified your CMD structure a bit:  

`CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--allow-root","--no-browser", "--ip", "0.0.0.0", "--NotebookApp.token=''","--NotebookApp.password=''"]`